# How do you Modify a function to insert a given number into the exact middle of the array and return the array.?

Tags: javascript

```
function insertIntoMiddle(array, item) {


}


const items = insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2);

console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2), 

console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3, 7, 9], 5);
```

Comment: Please, include any attempt you have tried to solve the problem first. Read more about how to ask on next link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Note also, that [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can help to do what you want, but it mutates the original array.

Comment: What if the array isn't even length, where would the new item go?

Answer (score 1):

You can use array [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and slice half of the array, slice will return a new array without affecting the original array:

```js
function insertIntoMiddle(array, item) {
  let len = Math.ceil(array.length / 2)
  return [
    ...array.slice(0, len),
    item,
    ...array.slice(len)
  ]
}


// Even length arrays:
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3], 2));
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 3, 7, 9], 5))

// Odd length arrays:
console.log(insertIntoMiddle([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9], 5))
```